# Updating belongs_to model via accepts_nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Unable to update state attribute of the Product model using accepts_nested_attributes. This is what JSON I post looks like:

> {"auth_token"=>"x", "product"=>{"caption"=>"x","state_attributes"=>{"id"=>"1"}}, "id"=>"x"}

All I need to do is to change referenced state. Thoughts?

---

## State Model

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

## Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :state, :state_attributes
  belongs_to :state
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :state, :allow_destroy => false
end
```

## Products Controller Update Action

```
def update
    
    product = Product.find_by_id( params[:id])
    
    if product && product.update_attributes(params[:product])
     respond_with(product, status: :updated, location: product)
    else
     respond_with(product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
 end
```

---

## Transaction Log

```
Started PUT "/products/1170.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-13 16:21:52 -0700
Processing by ProductsController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"x", "product"=>{"caption"=>"x", "state_attributes"=>{"id"=>"3"}}}, "id"=>"1170"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'x' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2014-01-13 23:20:46.614453', "current_sign_in_at" = '2014-01-13 23:21:52.251028', "sign_in_count" = 954, "updated_at" = '2014-01-13 23:21:52.251753' WHERE "users"."id" = 536
(6.5ms)  COMMIT
Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."user_id" = 536 AND "products"."id" = 1170 LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
State Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
(0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 404 Not Found in 15ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find State with ID=3 for Product with ID=1170):
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:81:in `update'

Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (5.8ms)
```

Comment: Any errors you're getting?

Comment: Please add the output of the web server when you make the post. It's easier to understand what is going on when we can see the actual request the server is getting, and what it does with it.

Comment: @ev - added transaction log to the post

Comment: You are trying to reset the id of the associated State. I guess you just want to associate a state to product, so you should just set the state_id attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sergio Aristizábal pointed out, I was trying to reset associated state instead of simply updating the id

> You are trying to reset the id of the associated State. I guess you just want to associate a state to product, so you should just set the state_id attribute.

With that, I updated Product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :state_id, :state_attributes
  belongs_to :state
end
```

Passed state id in the json

```
{"auth_token"=>"x", "product"=>{"caption"=>"x","state_id"=>"1"}, "id"=>"x"}
```

and everything worked like a charm. Thanks @Sergio